# Android custom circle progress bar

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

[image]

I want to design Circle Progress like above image.

**Even names and percentage Has to shown inside circle.**

Please suggest me any library or method to do so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

finally I found the solution from here,

https://github.com/ylyc/circular_progress_bar.

It works fine. thanks to all..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about any library that will do this for you, but I would just use the [Path class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) for the circular view and plain TextViews for the percentages.

Answer (score 1):

Write a custom view which would [draw an Arc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawArc(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint)) in the onDraw method.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this below link for clean master app kind of progress bar.[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213381/create-circular-progress-bar)

Comment: Can you post some content from the link?