# Static percentages icon in listview

Tags: android, list, listitem

I am making a list of students with their percent marks and in every list items I want to show their percentages not like dynamic progress bar but just a value inside ring .Is there a way to do so?
I also thought of downloading 1 to 100% icon and show in list views according to values but it will have 100 images ,is there a way to show percentage inside a list with name and a ring like

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android custom circle progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012065/android-custom-circle-progress-bar)

Comment: Please check this link might be helpful you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333866/how-to-create-a-circular-progressbar-in-android-which-rotates-on-it  or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776587/android-circular-determinate-progressbar

Comment: Yamen not duplicate because he wanted icon but I anted to add this bar with name in a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/cmll_progrssbar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="70"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle_progressbar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cmll_completed_per"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/cmll_progrssbar"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/cmll_progrssbar"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/cmll_progrssbar"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/cmll_progrssbar"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="70%" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**@drawable/circle_progressbar**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="270"
            android:toDegrees="270"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%" >
            <shape
                android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thicknessRatio="25.0" >
                <gradient
                    android:centerColor="@color/colorRed"
                    android:endColor="@color/colorRed"
                    android:startColor="@color/colorRed"
                    android:type="sweep" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: BUt I have to add it to list items not to a single that is the problem

Comment: you can also add this in  list items @Samuels what the proble in addinmg in list item

Comment: I have tried list with checkboxes and widgets but don'y know how to add it to listview with each name in front of it.I tried doing so but app is not working

Comment: @Samuels simple use custom layout with listview here is the demo tutorial https://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: @Samuels or your can go with Recyclerveiw https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/

Comment: I have seen his tutorial but he is using excessive code for many things thats why I left that link

Comment: rest is your choice  @Samuels Good luck

Comment: Thank you for giving your time